# Batch file to continuously hit enter key

Tags: batch-file, key, enter

I need a batch file that can continuously hit the enter key over and over. I honestly don't know the first thing about batch files but I am pretty sure this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SendKey.NET](http://sendkeysnet.blogspot.ca/2009/06/finally-keyboard-macro-you-can.html) freeware automation tool :

```
@echo off
start notepad.exe
SendKeys Hello World!{enter}
```

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) automation and scripting language might also help, it can simulate keystrokes.